# Javascript alert didn't appear

Tags: javascript

I feel I'm goona be rekt cause of asking this question. It is my first try in js (cause of needed).
Why I saw only `Always` alert from all of them?

```
<script src="./js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">alert("Never, but should it?");</script>
<script>alert("Always");</script>
<script>
    alert("Never");
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Never");
        $('#send').click(function() {
            alert("Never");
            $.post('index.py', {document.getElementById('input_text').value}, function(data){
                alert("Never");
                $('loader').html(data);
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Did you get any errors on the page? Are you sure jquery is being loaded with `./js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js`

Comment: I sure jquery there. Errors! Syntax, as in answer of guys lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you provide `src` in a `script` tag, then the javascript inside that tag will not be executed. After that, the first alert is `Always`, so you see that particular alert.

The third script contains a syntax error which is why you don't see the `Never` alerts after clicking `OK` on the `Always` alert

Replace

```
$.post('index.py', {document.getElementById('input_text').value}, function(data){
```

with

```
$.post('index.py', document.getElementById('input_text').value, function(data){
```

Answer (score 3):

The first script contains a `src` attribute, which prempts the content.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be
>   used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a
>   document. script elements with an src attribute specified should not
>   have a script embedded within its tags

The third script isn't executed because there's a syntax error.

Instead of

```
$.post('index.py', {document.getElementById('input_text').value}, function(data){
```

you probably want

```
$.post('index.py', document.getElementById('input_text').value, function(data){
```